# Replace a certain word randomly in a string a limited amount of times | Java

Tags: java, string, replace

I would like to replace a word from a String, just the same way `string.replace("word", "different word");` works, just a limited amount of times, lets say the word `apple` is mentioned 10 times in the string, i would like 5 of the `apples` to become `oranges`, how could i achieve that?

Also, if possible, i want it to be randomized, so it wouldn't go from first to the fifth `apple` but skip around  and for example change the `1st, 3rd, 4th, 7th, and 8th apple` would change.

Thanks!

Comment: Conceptual you can do a loop. You could create a random number for every occurence of apple in the text. Take the 5 with the highest value and replace them. What exactly is the problem? Can't you find the apple word or can't you replace them?

Comment: the point is to save time, the replaced string of course is not going to consist of only "apple", the string is about 500 words long, and there are many strings, not only one, im kind of trying to find a short cut to do it faster than looking for it and replacing it manually since i know i will be using it more in the future for my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do random substrings and use `replaceFirst` method on those. For substringing, use [substring(int beginIndex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) with a random begin index in between 0 and lengthOfOriginalWord-1-lengthOfWordToReplace interval.

```
    try {

        String originalWord = "alabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaORANGEORANGEaaaaaaa";
        String replacedWord = "ORANGE";
        String replacingWord = "APPLE";
        String substringedWord = "";

        // make sure this is smaller or equal with the number of occurrences, otherwise it's endless loop times
        int numberOfReplaces = 3;
        Random ran = new Random();
        int beginIndex;

        while (numberOfReplaces > 0) {
            // random index between 0 and originalWord.length()-1-replacedWord.length()
            beginIndex = ran.nextInt(originalWord.length()-1-replacedWord.length());
            substringedWord = originalWord.substring(beginIndex);
            if (substringedWord.contains(replacedWord)) {
                originalWord = originalWord.substring(0, beginIndex) + substringedWord.replaceFirst(replacedWord, replacingWord);
                numberOfReplaces--;                 
            }
        }
        System.out.println(originalWord);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        System.err.println("An error occurred: \n" + exc);
    }
```

Here's the output after running it five times:

`alabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaAPPLEAPPLEaaaaaaa
alabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaORANGEORANGEaaaaaaa
alabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaAPPLEORANGEaaaaaaa
alabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaAPPLEAPPLEaaaaaaa
alabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaportocalaORANGEalabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaportocalaAPPLEalabalaORANGEORANGEaaaaaaa`

Answer (score 1):

You can iteratively use `String#indexOf(String str, int fromIndex)` to find all of the starting indices of the word you want to replace, then randomly select a few of those indices (using e.g. a shuffled `ArrayList<Integer>`, or alternatively `ArrayList<Integer>#remove(Random#nextInt(ArrayList#size))`) and construct the new string using concatenated calls to `String#substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`

```
ArrayList<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<>();
int fromIndex = str.indexOf(searchString);
while(fromIndex != -1) {
    indices.add(fromIndex);
    fromIndex = str.indexOf(searchString, fromIndex + 1);
}
```

Comment: for `String.indexof(String str, int fromIndex)`, what exactly do i put for fromIndex? and can you explain about these functions a little more or give a good source for learning about it?

Comment: See my edit. `indexOf(String)` returns the first index of the search string; you then use `indexOf(String, fromIndex)` in a while loop to find the remaining indices; `indexOf(String, fromIndex)` searches for the next occurrence of the search string starting at fromIndex, for example if `str = "abba"` then `str.indexOf("a")` will return `0`, and then `str.indexOf("a", 1)` will return `3` - it began its search at index 1, i.e. the first `b`. See the [String javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more details.

Comment: ok, so after i have done all that and then removed a random word using `indices.remove(r.nextInt(indices.size()));` where `r` is a `Random` and `indices` is `ArrayList<Integer>` how would i reconstruct everything and remake the string with the new word?

Comment: Given a random `index` that you removed from the arraylist of indices, and given that the search string has lenth `len`, you would replace that single instance using `String newString = str.substring(0, index) + replacementString + str.substring(index + len)`; now you just need to create a loop that will take care of replacing **all** of the search string instances that you remove from the indices arraylist

Comment: i dont think im understanding this correctly, from what im seeing right now, its collection the amount of times the `SearchString` mentioned in the `String`, so  when i try to replace it, instead of going to a random beginning of a `SearchString` that was mentioned, it picks a random # from the # of times it is mentioned, for example if its mentioned 10 times, it picks a number between 1 and 10 and replaces the Characters in a random location between 1 and 10 to a different word.

Comment: is there an option to use `string.replace("str1","str2")` to replace only one word? i think that if there is it would be much easier to just use it in a loop for the amount of times i want it to be replaced

Comment: The arraylist contains all of the starting indices of the search string occurrence, for example with the string "abbaabba", with the search string "a", the indices arraylist would contain `{0, 3, 4, 7}`; I don't think that `replace` is an appropriate method to use here, because it will either replace all of the search strings or only the first search string - you're better off using `substring`, because then you can specify which search strings you're replacing.